# using sql regrex_replace to replace every word that starts with a # symbol with mask(word)

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, cockroachdb, cockroachcloud

I have text data as following in single column

```
This is a credit card number #341332123-432432-413213-13223. The CC # should be masked
This is a email #test@test.com The email address should be masked
This is a phone #555-555-5555, The phone number should be masked
```

I would like to replace the `#{token}` with `mask(token)`

e.g.

```
This is a credit card number mask(341332123-432432-413213-13223). The CC # should be masked
This is a email mask(test@test.com) The email address should be masked
This is a phone mask(555-555-5555), The phone number should be masked
```

Note. This is just text manipulation. I am not doing any masking in this step.

Comment: What does your current replacing code look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_replace`:

```
select regexp_replace(col_text, '(#)((?:[\d-]+)|(?:\w+@\w+\.\w+))', 'mask(\2)') from tbl
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YrfKAv9f).

Comment: Not my down vote. But I would guess it is because you posted a code only answer. No explanation for it.